# How to force return an HTTP response to an AJAX request in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.7

I use jQuery to quickly create single page experiences with `Laravel` templates. For example updating just the `#content` section of a webpage when a button (link) on the sidebar of an admin panel is clicked.

I usually add `success` and `error` callbacks to my request as such

```
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success:function(data){
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error) {
               //Error msg for Developers
               $('body').html('');
               $('body').prepend(xhr.responseText);
               $('body').append('XHR :'+xhr);
               $('body').append('STATUS :'+status);
               $('body').append('ERROR :'+error);
               // for users
               // $('.infoMsg').html("OOPS SOMETHING BAD HAPPENED!");
               // $('#infoModal').modal();


           }
       });
```

In the earlier versions of `Laravel` e.g `5.4` the JS inside the error function usually rendered errors from the backend just as normal HTTP responses (normal webpage). At that time, my guess is developers had to be intentional about the kind of response the wanted to send back and the default was HTTP. So if there was an error on the backend I would see something like  this (though this one is `5.7`)

[image]

So what's the issue here! Issue here is with 5.6 upwards I think, `Laravel` is able to detect the kind of request and sends responses in an appropriate format depending on the request type. In this case, it returns JSON responses for my AJAX requests. So now when there's and error in the backend, I would see something like this

[image]

Having errors displayed in such a messy way makes it harder for me to debug or even understand the error! I know it's possible to have the JSON appear in a better way however I want to know if it is possible (and infact a good solution) for me to just make `Laravel` return the HTTP response irrespective like in the previous versions?

When working with `GET` requests, If get and error from the backend while visiting a route like `list/products` for example, an easy way to debug is just to visit the url from the address bar and get the error in HTTP format directly however when working with `POST` request this is not the case. This is not really a "programming bug" or something but finding a convenient way to debug AJAX problems with `Laravel`. I would like to get my "good old laravel behavior" Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're after is a convenient way to debug exceptions, I might suggest https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

If you *really* want to force the pretty "Whoops" error response from your first screenshot for all ajax exceptions, you can replace your `\App\Exceptions\Handler::render` method with the code from its [parent class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L186), changing this:

```php
return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? $this->prepareJsonResponse($request, $e)
                    : $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
```

to this:

```
return $this->prepareResponse($request, $e);
```

Comment: thanks, Looks like a workable solution at first sight. Let me give it a try and mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: `public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        //return parent::render($request, $exception);
        return $this->prepareResponse($request, $exception);
    }` Cool. That worked thanks.